# How to do pattern match part of file names using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have like 10 files in blob where I need to pattern match part of the string name of the file, if matching then variable should be set to true. I will be getting the child names and file name from "Get metadata stage".

How to achieve this using Azure data factory?

Is it possible to match the pattern using Databricks Notebook by getting metadata using "Get metadata stage"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a **ForEach activity after Get Metadata activity** in ADF.

Please follow the demonstration below:

- My files in blob having **pattern** word as pattern.
  [image]
- Use Get Meta data activity to **pass this files list to ForEach**. Create an **array variable** in the pipeline.
- Give the ForEach Items dynamic content as below.

  `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

- Inside ForEach use an **append variable** to append our **file name and the True or false** based on the Pattern to the **array** we created earlier(`newfiles` in mycase).
- `ChildItems` gives the filenames and type of files, so take only the filenames from every item in ForEach and check with pattern.

`@concat(item().name,'-',if(contains(string(item().name),'pattern'),'true','false'))`

[image]

- Last **set variable** for result(optional and only for output show).

[image]

- **Output:**

[image]

> Is it possible to match the pattern using Databricks Notebook by getting metadata using "Get metadata stage"?

Yes, it is possible. If you want to **avoid the type of files** you can use an **append variable inside ForEach** to just pass the filename. If you want the type of files you can **pass the childItems from Get Metadata directly to Notebook**.

**To just pass File name**
[image]

pass this `newfiles` variable to **Databricks notebook** and use pattern matching condition in notebook.

[image]

Comment: just wanted to know , how to achieve this using databricks notebook, juts by taking output from GetMetadata stage and pattern matching in databricks notebook