# How to use output of ADF stage in databricks notebook

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I'm using get metadata stage in ADF to get the child values( file names) and Filetype.
I need to pattern match the file names using databricks notebook.
how to use the output of Get Metadata stage in ADF in databricks notebook and pattern match the part of string file names?

Answer (score 0):

The `activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` gives the file names and file types as array. But currently, it is not supported to pass the array variable from notebook activity to databricks.

So, **pass it as string** and do the remaining work in databricks notebook.

Please follow the demonstration below:

- First create a [linked service for the databricks workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#create-an-azure-databricks-linked-service) in ADF and give it to the Notebook activity.
- Then create the notebook in the databricks and give notebook to notebook activity in ADF. You can find about it in the documentation above. Here my notebook name is `forADF`.

[image]

- Now Go to the Databricks notebook and use the below code.

**Code:**

```
data=dbutils.widgets.get("names")   # data from Get Meta data activity
mypattern="pattern"   # Our Pattern
print(data)
print(type(data))
print(mypattern)

data=data[1:len(data)-1]   # To remove first [ and last ]
data=data.replace('{','')  # removes all { in data
data=data.replace('}','')  # removes all } in data
print(data)

files_list=data.split(",")   # makes an array of file names and types as strings.
print(files_list)

result=[]
for i in range(0,len(files_list),2):   # File names are 2 positions seperated from start in the list
    if(mypattern in files_list[i]):
        t=files_list[i]+" -> "+files_list[i+1]+" -> "+"Pattern - True"
        result.append(t)
    else:
        t=files_list[i]+" -> "+files_list[i+1]+" -> "+"Pattern - False"
        result.append(t)
        
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

My Outputs for your reference:

1. **Get the paremeter from activity:**

[image]

2. **Do some operations on it to do pattern match:**

[image]

3. **Pattern match and set true or false.**

[image]

- If you want to **avoid the file type** use a **ForEach and store only the file names in an array variable** like this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72947857/how-to-do-pattern-match-part-of-file-names-using-adf/72950065#72950065) and pass it in the Notebook activity as string.

  `@string(variable("variable_name"))`
- Now you can **remove the [] and split it** and store the file names list in databricks code. You can do the **step 3 above by iterating one position** at a time.